# Postgres dev db not uploading to Heroku with pg:transfer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, migration

I'm trying to clone my development postgres db to Heroku with the command:

```
heroku pg:transfer -t postgres://localhost/MentorConnect_development -f postgres://mbarwrandompn:DaVXj1_AVytIgLU3lsyEKjU8eC@ec2-23-21-129-229.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d4ahirandom
```

(changed the url for privacy)

It seems to work -- I get a lot of lines going with my database columns and everything with no errors. However when I go into the Heroku rails console, the database is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your command there is transferring from Heroku to localhost, not development > heroku as per your question.

Also, it's much easier to use the colour of the database rather than the full URL (get it from `heroku config` output) eg;

```
heroku pg:transfer -f postgres://localhost/mydb -t COLOUR
```

where COLOUR is from the `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOUR_URL` from the `heroku config` output.

Comment: Ack you're right... I just overwrote the database I needed. Ugh!

Comment: always worth double checking and then triple checking the warning messages it gives you when you issue a destructive command like this. We've all done it (once).